# how to handle browser close case (action/event) on RxJava2 Flowable with SSE (Server-Sent-Events)

Tags: rx-java2, publish, server-sent-events, reactive-streams

I want to get notified if the consumer close the browser or somehow disconnects from SSE stream.

as an example when connection start with curl, the `doOnSubscribe` operation is called and the `connectedDeliveryCount`  is getting increased but never decreased although I have closed the connection on purpose with ctrl-c. none of the events are being called like `doOnComplete` or `doOnTerminate` or `doOnCancel`

sample connection with get

```
faruk@virtualBox:/usr/lib/jvm$ curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/delivery-stream -v
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /delivery-stream HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
^C
faruk@virtualBox:/usr/lib/jvm$
```

code block :

```
static AtomicInteger connectedDeliveryCount = new AtomicInteger();

@GetMapping(path = "/delivery-stream", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flowable<String> deliveryStream() {
        return ReactiveStreamsOrderService.deliverySubjectToFlowable()
                .doOnCancel(() -> System.out.println("{doOnCancel}: xxx"))
                .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("{doOnComplete}: xxx"))
                .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> System.out.println("{doOnSubscribe}: xxx"))
                .doOnTerminate(() -> System.out.println("{doOnTerminate}: xxx"))
                .onErrorReturn(throwable -> "xxx"+throwable.getMessage())
                .doOnSubscribe(subscription -> connectedDeliveryCount.incrementAndGet())
                .doOnTerminate(() -> connectedDeliveryCount.decrementAndGet())
                ;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get notified if the consumer close the browser or somehow disconnects from SSE stream.

When you send something on the socket, if the client has disconnected you get a socket closed error. In my experience, you don't discover this until you try to use a TCP/IP socket.

So the solution is to send regular "keep-alive" messages down the socket, even when you don't have any information to send to them. For instance, every 10 seconds, send a timestamp, or server status string. When this triggers an error you know the client disconnected at some point in the last 10 seconds.

I don't know rx-java, sorry, but my guess would be you would get the error in your `doOnTerminate` handler.